# Enable horizontal scrollbar in each flex items when squeezed beyond initial width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

What I would like to achieve is: When the side bar appears(click anywhere in the demo below), both the `child-1`(blue) and `child-2`(black) would retain their initial width by each enabling horizontal scrolling.

```js
document.body.onclick = () => document.querySelector('.sidebar').classList.toggle('hide')
```

```css
html, body {height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden; }

.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sidebar {
  flex: 0 0 12rem;
  background: green;
}
.sidebar.hide {
  margin-left: -12rem;
}

.parent { display: flex; flex: 1; flex-shrink: 0; overflow: hidden;}

.child-1, .child-2 {
  flex: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.child-1 { background: blue;}
.child-2 { background: black;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar hide"></div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child-1"></div>
    <div class="child-2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do You mean like so:

I have included a div `child-inner` with a fixed width. (for overflow, you have to specify some sort of a fixed-width)

```js
document.body.onclick = () => document.querySelector('.sidebar').classList.toggle('hide')
```

```css
html, body {height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden; }

.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sidebar {
  flex: 0 0 12rem;
  background: green;
}
.sidebar.hide {
  margin-left: -12rem;
}

.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.child-1, .child-2 {
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.child-inner{
  width: 50vw;
}

.child-1 { background: blue;}
.child-2 { background: black;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar hide"></div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child-1">
      <div class="child-inner">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="child-2">
      <div class="child-inner">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: initially, there shouldn't be any horizontal scrollbar coz the content are wrapped to whatever width after using flexbox(in this case `flex: 1`). Then when sidebar is shown, the containers' width is varied while maintaining its initial width, hence the horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: there schuldn‘t be a initial scrollbar the problem is, that you have to define some sort of „static“ width to enable the overflow. In your example, that is 50vw. Or you can use javascript to „freez“ the with when the content was loaded